# A blank GUI opens when i click the button on the home GUI

Tags: java, swing

So I am walking on a density calculator GUI and i have some problems.
this is my Code for the home page

```
package DensityCalc;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Home extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static Home frame = new Home();
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*UIManager um = new UIManager();
        um.put("OptionPane.background", Color.blue);
        um.put("Panel.background", Color.yellow);
        um.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Cinzel Decorative", Font.BOLD, 13));*/
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
            
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"DENSITY CALCULATOR");
                    
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Home() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 205);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 166);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 204));
        contentPane.add(panel);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Mass");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                Masses l1frame = new Masses();
                l1frame.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Volume");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                vol window1 = new vol ();
                window1.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Density");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                Den l1frame = new Den();
                l1frame.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
        
    }
    
}
```

when I run it I get this

now this is my code for the density gui

```
package DensityCalc;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class vol extends Home {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    vol window = new vol();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public vol() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 204));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        
        
        JLabel speed = new JLabel("Mass (kg)");
        speed.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        speed.setFont(new Font("Cinzel Decorative", Font.BOLD, 16));
        speed.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        speed.setBounds(10, 57, 152, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(speed);
        
        textfield1 = new JTextField();
        textfield1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        textfield1.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
        textfield1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        textfield1.setBounds(174, 56, 139, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textfield1);
        textfield1.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("vol (mÂ³)");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Cinzel Decorative", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 131, 152, 52);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        textfield2 = new JTextField();
        textfield2.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        textfield2.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
        textfield2.setBounds(174, 100, 139, 39);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textfield2);
        textfield2.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblNewLabel_2.setToolTipText("Answer");
        lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        lblNewLabel_2.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.background"));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(173, 151, 203, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
        
    
        
        
        JButton ansButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        ansButton.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        ansButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        ansButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                double mass, vol, dens;
                try {
                    mass = Double.parseDouble(textfield1.getText());
                    dens = Double.parseDouble(textfield2.getText());
                    if (mass > 0 && dens > 0) { 
                        vol = mass / dens;
                    
                        lblNewLabel_2.setText(Double.toString((double) vol));
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Positive Numbers");
                    }
                }   
                catch(Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid Values");
                }
            }
        });
        ansButton.setFont(new Font("Cinzel Decorative", Font.BOLD, 16));
        ansButton.setBounds(0, 203, 162, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ansButton);
        
        
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Density (Kg/mÂ³)");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Cinzel Decorative", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 105, 152, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Back");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home f = new Home();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 0, 117, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        
        
    }
}
```

when i run it i get this

Now when ever I go on the home gui and click the volume button it does not take me to the volume gui, instead a blank gui is opened. But when i run the volume gui and I go back, I am taken to home, I press the volume button on home and its a blank gui that opens. I dont understand the problem. I hope i explained myself well

Answer (score 0):

General comments about Swing design:

1. Class names should start with an upper case character. You have two classes "Home" and "vol". Be consistent.
2. Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
3. An application should only have a single JFrame. If you need child windows then typically you would use a modal `JDialog`.
4. Variable names should be meaningful. Why would you call a button "btnNewButton_2". If you have multiple buttons you lose track of what button 1, 2, or 3 refer too. A name like "volumeButton" if far more descriptive.
5. You should only extend a class when you add functionality to the class. You should not be extending a JFrame. Adding components to a frame does NOT change the functionality of the frame, so you should not be extending JFrame. Instead your main() method should simply create a JFrame and then add a panel to the frame.
6. You are incorrectly using a static variable for the frame. There is no need for a static variable.

With regards to your question I suspect the problem is that your "vol" class extends the "Home" class. This is unnecessary.

The "Volume" dialog functions independently of the "Home" frame. That is the Home frame should simply display the modal "Volume" dialog. When you close the Volume dialog focus will automatically return to the Home frame.